# Installing rpy2 to work with R 3.4.0 on OSX

Tags: r, conda, python-3.6, rpy2, libiconv

I would like to use some R packages requiring R version 3.4 and above. I want to access these packages in python (3.6.1) through rpy2 (2.8).

I have R version 3.4 installed, and it is located in `/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources` However, when I use `pip3 install rpy2` to install and use the python 3.6.1 in `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin/python3.6)` as my interpreter, I get the error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "/Users/vincentliu/PycharmProjects/magic/rpy2tester.py", line 1, in 
>       from rpy2 import robjects
>     File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rpy2/robjects/**init**.py", line 16, in 
>       import rpy2.rinterface as rinterface
>     File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rpy2/rinterface/**init**.py", line 92, in 
>       from rpy2.rinterface._rinterface import (baseenv,
>   ImportError: dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rpy2/rinterface/_rinterface.cpython-36m-darwin.so, 2): Library not loaded: @rpath/libiconv.2.dylib
>     Referenced from: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rpy2/rinterface/_rinterface.cpython-36m-darwin.so
>     Reason: Incompatible library version: _rinterface.cpython-36m-darwin.so requires version 8.0.0 or later, but libiconv.2.dylib provides version 7.0.0

Which first seemed like a problem caused by Anaconda, and so I remove all Anaconda-related files but the problem persists.

I then uninstalled rpy2, reinstalled Anaconda and used `conda install rpy2` to install, which also installs R version 3.3.2 through Anaconda. I can then change the interpreter to `/anaconda/bin/python` and can use rpy2 fine, but I couldn't use the R packages I care about because they need R version 3.4 and higher. Apparently, the oldest version Anaconda can install is 3.3.2, so is there any way I can use rpy2 with R version 3.4?

I can see two general solutions to this problem. One is to install rpy2 through conda and then somehow change its depending R to the 3.4 one in the system. Another solution is to resolve the error

> Incompatible library version: _rinterface.cpython-36m-darwin.so requires version 8.0.0 or later, but libiconv.2.dylib provides version 7.0.0

After much struggling, I've found no good result with either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I uninstalled rpy2 and reinstalled with `--verborse`. I then found

> ld: warning: ignoring file /opt/local/lib/libpcre.dylib, file was built for x86_64 which is not the architecture being linked (i386): /opt/local/lib/libpcre.dylib
>       ld: warning: ignoring file /opt/local/lib/liblzma.dylib, file was built for x86_64 which is not the architecture being linked (i386): /opt/local/lib/liblzma.dylib
>       ld: warning: ignoring file /opt/local/lib/libbz2.dylib, file was built for x86_64 which is not the architecture being linked (i386): /opt/local/lib/libbz2.dylib
>       ld: warning: ignoring file /opt/local/lib/libz.dylib, file was built for x86_64 which is not the architecture being linked (i386): /opt/local/lib/libz.dylib
>       ld: warning: ignoring file /opt/local/lib/libiconv.dylib, file was built for x86_64 which is not the architecture being linked (i386): /opt/local/lib/libiconv.dylib
>       ld: warning: ignoring file /opt/local/lib/libicuuc.dylib, file was built for x86_64 which is not the architecture being linked (i386): /opt/local/lib/libicuuc.dylib
>       ld: warning: ignoring file /opt/local/lib/libicui18n.dylib, file was built for x86_64 which is not the architecture being linked (i386): /opt/local/lib/libicui18n.dylib
>       ld: warning: ignoring file /opt/local/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/R, file was built for x86_64 which is not the architecture being linked (i386): /opt/local/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/R

So I supposed the reason is the architecture incompatibility of the libiconv in `opt/local`, causing make to fall back onto the outdate libiconv in `usr/lib`. This is strange because my machine should be running on x86_64 not i386. I then tried `export ARCHFLAGS="-arch x86_64"` and reinstalled libiconv using port. This resolved the problem.

Comment: Cheers ... that finally worked. Even though it is really ugly to be forced to mix different package managers here.

Comment: @Vince Could you explain more about the commands? where did you added export archflags commands? using pip?

Answer (score 0):

I had uninstall the version pip installed and install from source `python setup.py install` on the download `https://bitbucket.org/rpy2/rpy2/downloads/`. FWIW not using Anaconda at all either.